# Changing the format of name of fasta sequences in a file including nucleotide number in sequence

Tags: python

I don't know much programming but I am learning Linux and Python.
I have a sequence file which has 13500 sequences in it. and the name of the sequences is in one form

```
>MP_scaffold_001_1
```

I want to count number of nucleotides in each sequence and want to change its name to

```
>MP_scaffold_001_1 <TAB> <Number_of_nucleotides>
```

Comment: How does the file specify how many nucleotides are in each sequence?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget typically a FASTA file contains one or more lines starting with `>` giving metadata about the sequence, then the sequence itself is on the next line not starting with `>`. The sequence is just a string of letters, in this case DNA - A, T, C, and G.

Comment: It would be better if you provide an example of input data (not a complete file, jest few chunks demostrating format)

Comment: Ahha, I've taken a look on the format in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with biological sequences in Python, you can't go wrong with [Biopython](http://biopython.org). The [`SeqIO`](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) class contains tools for working with sequences, including those in FASTA format. The following code should get you started:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
with open("input.fasta", "r") as input, open("output.fasta", "w") as output:
    for seq in SeqIO.parse(input, "fasta"):
        length = "\t%d" % len(seq)
        seq.description += length
        SeqIO.write(seq, output, "fasta")
```

This code first opens two file handlers, `input` and `output`, that will automatically be closed when the processing is complete. Next, each sequence (`seq`) in `input` is iterated through using the [`SeqIO.parse()`](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO#Sequence_Input) method. The length of the sequence is determined by using Python's built-in `len()` function, and a formatting string is built using the tab character `\t` and the number returned by `len()`. Then, the `description` string of each `seq` is modified by adding the contents of the `length` variable onto the end of it. Finally, the newly-modified record is written to the output file in FASTA format.

I'd highly recommend reading through Biopython's [Tutorial and Cookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html) to familiarize yourself with all that the module provides.